# Ignore particular WHERE criteria

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

I want to execute a parameterized query to perform a search by user-supplied parameters. There are quite a few parameters and not all of them are going to be supplied all the time. How can I make a standard query that specifies all possible parameters, but ignore some of these parameters if the user didn't choose a meaningful parameter value?

Here's an imaginary example to illustrate what I'm going for

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name AND age = :age AND sex = :sex';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':first_name' => 'John', ':age' => '27');
```

Obviously, this will not work because the number of provided parameters does not match the number of expected parameters. Do I have to craft the query every time with only the specified parameters being included in the WHERE clause, or is there a way to get some of these parameters to be ignored or always return true when checked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE (first_name = :first_name or :first_name is null)
AND (last_name = :last_name or :last_name is null)
AND (age = :age or :age is null)
AND (sex = :sex or :sex is null)
```

When passing parameters, supply `null` for the ones you don't need.

Note that to be able to run a query this way, `emulation mode` for PDO have to be turned `ON`

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. This'll match is `first_name` has a matching value, or if it's null. But from what I understand, he wants `first_name` to match in anything (as if there were no WHERE clause for that column at all).

Comment: @netcoder it is not checking if first_name is null, it is checking if `(first_name = @var or @var is null)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Quite ingenious.

Comment: @juergen d  It gives a "number of bound variables" PDOException if no array elements do not match. See my [comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11232601/699091)

Answer (score 2):

First, start by changing your `$sql` string to simply:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM people WHERE 1 = 1';
```

The `WHERE 1 = 1` will allow you to not include any additional parameters...

Next, selectively concatenate to your `$sql` string any additional parameter that has a meaningful value:

```
$sql .= ' AND first_name = :first_name'
$sql .= ' AND age = :age'
```

Your `$sql` string now only contains the parameters that you plan on providing, so you can proceed as before:

```
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':first_name' => 'John', ':age' => '27');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't solve your problem by changing your query... There are several libraries that help with assembling queries. I've used `Zend_Db_Select` in the past but every framework likely has something similar:

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select;

$select->from('people');

if (!empty($lastName)) {
  $select->where('lastname = ?', $lastname);
}

$select->order('lastname desc')->limit(10);

echo $select; // SELECT * FROM people WHERE lastname = '...' ORDER BY lastname desc LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the solution given by @juergen but it gives a PDOException since number of bound variables does not match. The following (not so elegant) code works regardless of no of parameters:

```
function searchPeople( $inputArr )
{
  $allowed = array(':first_name'=>'first_name', ':last_name'=>'last_name', ':age'=>'age', ':sex'=>'sex');

  $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM sf_guard_user WHERE 1 = 1';

  foreach($allowed AS $key => $val)
  {
      if( array_key_exists( $key, $inputArr ) ){
          $sql .= ' AND '. $val .' = '. $key;
      }
  }

  $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $query->execute( $inputArr );
  return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$result = searchPeople(array(':first_name' => 'John', ':age' => '27'));
```

Comment: Are you using named parameters and the latest version of PHP+PDO? It works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm using named parameters and PHP 5.3.5 with mysqlnd 5.0.7. The above code works fine, but if I only replace the $sql string with that of @juergen d gives PDOException. His method is certainly more elegant, and I'd prefer to use it. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You have to supply null for unwanted parameters.

Comment: Yes. That explains it. I thought you wanted a variable array size as input.